Closed form for $A = \sum_{a>1,b>1}\dfrac{1}{(2 a^2 + 3 b^2)^2}$?
Is there a closed form for
$A = \sum_{a>1,b>1}\dfrac{1}{(2 a^2 + 3 b^2)^2}$
??
We know
$$ \sum_{m,n = - \infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m^2 + 58 n^2} = - \frac{\pi \ln( 27 + 5 \sqrt {29})}{\sqrt {58}} $$
Where the sum omits the case $n = m = 0$ ofcourse.
This last identity is related to the fact that $m^2 + 58 n^2$ is a norm of a ring.
But $2 a^2 + 3 b^2$ is not the norm of a ring or related to any ring as far as I know.
So far the main question

Related perhaps I wonder about the zero's of the related zeta function
$f(s) = 1 + \sum_{a>1,b>1}\dfrac{1}{(2 a^2 + 3 b^2)^s}$

It is known that
$$\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\setminus{(0,0)}}\frac{1}{(2m^2+3n^2)^s}=\zeta(s)L_{\chi_{24}(5)}(s)-L_{\chi_3(2)}(s)L_{\chi_8(5)}(s)$$, but $L_{\chi_{24}(5)}$ and $L_{\chi_3(2)}$ are only known to be elementary at the odd values of $s$, so if your sum were elementary we would have a nontrivial relation among special values of $L$-functions.

@KBDave Could you elaborate plz ? I assume you are talking about some dirichlet series multiplied and added but I am not so familiar with the notation or how you arrived at them.

This should not be very simple since
$$\sum_{b=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(2 a^2 + 3 b^2)^2}=-\frac{1}{8\, a^4}+\frac{\pi  \coth
   \left(\pi a\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \right)}{8 \sqrt{6}\, a^3}+\frac{\pi^2
   \text{csch}^2\left(\pi a\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \right)}{24\, a^2}$$
Beside the first term whose sum is $-\frac{\pi ^4}{720}$, I do not see what to do.
The partial sums converge quite fast.
The continuous case would not be simpler since the required integrals do not exist (so no hope for a try with Euler-MacLaurin summation in its simplest form).

Could you explain K B Dave's comment plz ? Im not sure what he did. I assume the analogue of integrals involving rational expressions that can be done if we first do partial fractions on the integrand. Decomposition in simple fractions or whatever it is called in english. It seems like some kind of dirichlet series.
